# Interpolation of data

Tags: interpolation

I'm new with the program and I want to know if I can use it for my master thesis so I was trying it out and have the following question:

Is it possible to interpolate data out of 5 weather stations (the data is handed in an excel spreadsheet format) to make weather maps of a whole state more accurate?

Can anyone give me a hint how to start?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which program, software ???

Comment: By "I'm new with the program", do you mean you're starting out with QGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very poorly constructed but I will try to give you some steps suggestion:

1) Organize your data into a csv file containing XYZ where X and Y are the coordinates of each weather station and Z is the variable you want to interpolate, e.g. rainfall.

2) Import it to qgis -> Check this online tutorial: http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/01/importing-spreadsheets-or-csv-files-to.html

3) Go to the Plugins menu, then Interpolation > Interpolation. If you don't see this option enable at the Plugin Manage.

4) Select as input the layer of point representing the stations

5) Select one interpolation method e.g. Inverse Distance Weighting (IDW)

6) Try different parameters to ensure a good interpolation.

If you need more specific explanation try to give us more details!

Comment: This is a good attempt to answer a question that is too broad and ill-stated to be answerable.  But how, exactly, is one supposed to obtain a "good interpolation" by "trying different parameters"? How accurate do you suppose state-wide interpolation of meteorological data from *five* monitoring stations is going to be? That appears to be the crux of the matter. At a minimum, additional information has to be used for the interpolation, such as using elevation as a regressor.

Comment: Thank you EGB, yes the question was very poorly constructed, for which I'm sorry. Let me try what you suggest! Thankyou so much... 

Have a good one!

Comment: yes it worked! thank you so much! I will be validating the info and if any doubts on how to make better approximations I'll let you know!